# Why do the labels on my custom user control cause the mouseleave event to fire?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have written a custom WPF UserControl. It's a square with a `Grid` named `Base`. To that grid I add an ellipse and two labels (`volume` and `location`), which are populated with text pulled from the properties of an object which is given as a parameter upon control instantiation.

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EasyHyb.SampleWellControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Grid x:Name="Base">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the constructor/event functions in the codebehind:

```
public SampleWellControl(int size, SourceSample sample)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.sample = sample;
            this.Width = this.Height = size;
            this.selected = SelectionStatus.Unselected;

            double spacing = size / 4;

            volume = new Label();
            location = new Label();

            volume.Content = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sample.volume);
            location.Content = sample.well.well;

            volume.HorizontalAlignment = location.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            volume.FontFamily = location.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Meiryo UI");
            volume.FontWeight = location.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            volume.Background = location.Background = Base.Background = this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            volume.Margin = new Thickness(0, spacing, 0, 0);
            location.Margin = new Thickness(0, spacing * 2, 0, 0);

            well = new Ellipse();
            well.Width = well.Height = this.Width;
            well.StrokeThickness = 3;

            Base.Children.Add(well);
            Base.Children.Add(volume);
            Base.Children.Add(location);

            this.MouseEnter += SampleWellControl_MouseEnter;
            this.MouseLeave += SampleWellControl_MouseLeave;
            this.MouseUp += SampleWellControl_MouseUp;

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

            UpdateFillAndStroke();
        }

    void SampleWellControl_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RevertWell();
    }

    void SampleWellControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HighlightWell();
    }

    public void HighlightWell()
    {
        if (this.selected == SelectionStatus.Pooled)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (this.selected == SelectionStatus.Unselected)
        {
            this.well.Stroke = this.strokes[SelectionStatus.Selected];
        }
        else
        {
            this.well.Stroke = this.strokes[SelectionStatus.Unselected];
        }
    }

    public void RevertWell()
    {
        if (this.selected == SelectionStatus.Pooled)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (this.selected == SelectionStatus.Unselected)
        {
            this.well.Stroke = this.strokes[SelectionStatus.Unselected];
        }
        else
        {
            this.well.Stroke = this.strokes[SelectionStatus.Selected];
        }
    }
```

Basically, when the mouse enters the control, the stroke of the ellipse should change unless the well has undergone an operation to give it a "Pooled" status.

When the mouse enters the control, it responds exactly as I expect: the `MouseEnter` event handler fires. However, when a user moves the mouse over one of the labels inside the control, the `MouseLeave` event fires. So even though the label is ostensibly part of the control The pictures below show what I'm talking about. Print Screen removes the cursors, but I put blue dots to indicate where the cursor is:

Responding properly:

[image: Responding properly]

Now it seems to think the mouse has left the control:

[image: Not responding properly]

I've tried adding MouseEnter and MouseLeave event handlers to the labels, but they don't fire. The cursor also changes from a hand to a pointer when the labels are moused over. I've tried adding MouseEnter and MouseLeave event handlers to the control after it's instantiated within another class. I added transparent backgrounds to the Grid, control, and labels, but that didn't make any difference either.

I also checked in my MouseLeave event handler to see if the mouse was over the control, and it seems that the control is not detecting the cursor as being over the control itself:

```
if(!this.IsMouseOver)
{
    RevertWell();
}
//also tried IsMouseDirectlyOver
```

I would like `MouseLeave` to fire only when the cursor exits the square bounds of the control. How can I accomplish this while keeping the labels?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing in the `SampleWellControl_MouseEnter` method, the `SampleWellControl_MouseLeave` method, or the `UpdateFillAndStroke` method, but when I implement your code, it performs as expected.  You may want to look into one of the 3 methods for which you don't have code listed.  I suspect the trouble lies with one of them.

Comment: @Stewbob Thanks! I edited the post accordingly. Are you saying that MouseLeave does *not* fire when you mouse over the label?

Comment: Correct.  The MouseLeave does **not** fire when I mouse over the labels.

Comment: @DeeDee any reason you're not hooking to the events in XAML?  And have you tried making the Grid's IsHitTestVisible=False?

Comment: @NETscape No real reason why I'm doing it in codebehind. I tried hooking up the handlers via XAML but that didn't change anything. I also tried adding IsHitTestVisible, but that also didn't change anything. Great suggestions though, thanks!

Comment: @Stewbob Hmmmm, when I put the control in a different project it worked as expected. Seems like there's something else at play here. Time for me to dig a little deeper, I guess. Thanks for testing and reporting back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well shucks, after a lot of searching around it turns out the problem was indeed contained within another control. I had another `UserControl` class, `EmptyWellControl`, which had a `Label`. The text position within the label was calculated using the `Label`'s `Height` property, which resulted in a nonsense value that made the label extend vertically well beyond the dimensions of the window. The label didn't have a background, but nevertheless interfered with the controls whose path it crossed. Since the empty and sample wells were all laid out on the same grid, every `SampleWellControl` was affected by these labels.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

on all of your objects added to Base:

```
volume = new Label();
volume.IsHitTestVisible="False";
```

and then your container which has the events, give a background

```
<Grid x:Name="Base" Background="White">
```

(Also I wanted to comment but reputation is stupid)

Comment: I'm already giving the `Base` Grid a transparent background in the code above, but I'll try the first suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Transparent does not behave the same as other colors. Try removing the transparency in other areas if this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I added the transparency early on as a troubleshooting step. I tried your "isHitTestVisible" suggestion and it didn't work, but it was a great idea. There must be something else at work here outside of the control.